# How to run multiple instances of the same service in Pacemaker cluster

Tags: linux, cluster, pacemaker, corosync

I need to set multiple application instances groups (vip, service, iscsi disk) colocation so each group runs at the separate cluster node.
I know that Pacemaker offers group attributes and rules for this, but I couldn't find an example.

**For instance:**

Group A consist of resources A1, A2, A3 with ordering and colocation set.
Group B consist of the same number of resources B1, B2, B3, ordering and collocations.

There might be more of such groups (up to 14).

I want Pacemaker to run each group at its own dedicated node, like the following:
A(A1,A2,A3) on node 1, B(B1,B2,B3) on node 2, C on 3, D on 4, E on 5, etc.

How do I do that?

PS: Possible solution would be to map each group to a particular node using group stickiness, but I would like to avoid such setup since this requires manual verification of the current mapping configuration before each new service provision. I'm looking for the solution where Pacemaker is doing this automatically.

Comment: You mean A(A1,A2,A3) on node 1, B(B1,B2,B3) on node 2, C on 3, D on 4, E on 5, etc.?

Comment: @Lenniey right, exactly like that. Updated the question

Comment: I don't get why it wouldn't work? What's the problem?

Comment: You mean why two service instances can't be run at the single node? Technically I think it is possible to run them at the single machine (however with linux containers this will be much simpler). But I have business requirement for one service instance = one dedicated machine.

Comment: No, I mean what keeps you from configuring it the way you need it? What is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how :) this is the question I posted. Need a working example... Couldn't google anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98457/discussion-between-kenuat-and-lenniey).